# Photo manipulation for systemspace/Tsuki Project/cyberpunk aesthetic

Tags: gimp, photo-editing

"Systemspace", or The Tsuki Project, was an alternate reality game (ARG) which ran from 2017-2020. The history of the site, along with archive, is currently maintained at https://www.systemspace.network/ for art preservation reasons. See the [main site](https://classic.systemspace.network/) for reference.

Although it was eventually shut down, the background images are unforgettable and something I want to replicate. My first attempt with [a sample photo](https://i.pinimg.com/originals/9a/0c/57/9a0c57b4eac71a7996ec830e179c95ac.jpg) in GIMP used the curves adjustment and got pretty close.

[image: Manipulation attempt for dataverses.png]

But to get some other images, like "index.png", the curves adjustment gets the black parts and the reduction of the colour space right, but I'm not sure how to proceed [with this second sample image](https://66.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_m9neddCKha1ry21hqo1_r1_640.jpg) with getting yellows and blues like in the reference. I am stuck with yellows and greens, because of the way the colour adjustment sliders have each colour opposed to each other. The colours also look very harsh. My attempt with the color adjustment setting are shown.

[image: Manipulation attempt for index.png]

**The preferred answer will show:**

- how to increase how "blown out" and exposed the bright areas are in the "dataverses" image,
- how to achieve the soft yellows and blues of the "index" image while keeping the dark areas dark
- anything else obvious that I am missing to make the image styles more closely match the references.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the color histogram of your example image, it seems that the high values of green and blue are cut off (and a bit more so for blue), so try curves with a bell shaped curve on the right for each channel:

[image]

Comment: This works pretty well. Colours still look not as yellow or soft as I like, but it's good enough for an answer. I didn't even know I could modify each colour channel as its own curve.